# Difference between InputStream.read(byte b) and BufferedInputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

I just saw that the `InputStream` ([link to Java 11 API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html)) class has a method `read(byte[] b)` to read the data stream byte wise. Isn't that a kind of "buffered reading"?

Further I saw, that the `BufferedInputStream` ([link to Java 11 API)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) does not have an own implementation of `read(byte[] b)`. It is using the method of its parent class `FilterInputStream`.

So, does the `InputStream` class also support buffered reading? And where is the difference to the class `BufferedInputStream`?

### Edit

Corrected "`read(byte b)`" to "`read(byte[] b)`".

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract class, not an interface! And it does provide a `read(byte)` method.. And this one is a buffer, isn't it?

Comment: The difference is that when you read one or a buffer of bytes using an InputStream, it just reads that or these bytes (maximum), and nothing more. When using a BufferedInputStream, reading a single byte or a buffer of bytes actually loads a bigger chunk of bytes and keeps them in memory, readily available for the next reads.

Comment: So if you read from a file byte by byte, or 10 bytes by 10 bytes using a FileInputStream, you'll make a lot of file system reads, whereas if you use a BufferedInputStream, the first read will actually read something like 8Kb from the file system, and the next reads will just read from the in-memory buffer, making it much faster. In short, it behaves as described in the javadoc, that you should read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you mean `byte[] b`, not `byte b`.

As per the Javadoc, the default implementation for `read(byte[] b)` is simply calling `read(b, 0, b.length)`.  As this method is overridden in the `BufferedInputStream`, you can say that `read(byte[] b)` is, for all intents and purposes, also overridden.

The additional functionality provided by `BufferedInputStream` is support for the `mark` and `reset` methods, which effectively allows you to bookmark a point in the stream and re-read from that bookmark.  The buffer maintains the bytes required to support this operation.  Otherwise, it will simply read what is available at the time, without any buffering.

Comment: In the API is nothing mentioned, that "`read(byte[] b)` is simply calling `read(b, 0, b.length)`"?! I can only read "The read(b) method for class InputStream has the same effect as: read(b, 0, b.length)".

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)

Comment: Ok. Thanks! But, does e.g. `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` with `byte[] b = new byte[1024]` also do a kind of "buffered reading", thus reading 1024 bytes at once from the file system?

Comment: @mrbela read my comments, under your question. A BufferedInputStream uses an **internal** buffer, that is used whether or not you read one byte at a time, or N bytes at a time; That's what makes it a buffered stream. Also read the javadoc, that explains the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

So [InputStream](https://coderfoobar.com/what-is-a-java-inputstream/) is an Interface and BufferedInputStream is an implementation.
A BufferedInputStream wraps around another InputStream like FileInputStream and buffers data.
What BufferedInputStream does is that it collects multiple chunks of bytes before return so that you can read larger chunks of data at once for performance.

You can check out this [optimization example](https://coderfoobar.com/how-to-write-efficient-code-using-java-inputstream/).